# Accessing variable from within the app in Flutter

Tags: variables, flutter, singleton, global

I'm new to Flutter. I came from Android background.

My questions is, what's the best way to save/retrieve value from the variable within the app. Let's say `userId`. If user logs in, we set it, when user logs out, we reset it. And we can retrieve it from any screen.

In Android I usually have UserManager singleton where I keep my `userId`. Therefore I can retrieve it from anywhere.

What's the best practice with it in Flutter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use either some kind of state management like Provider or even Redux. But for something simples is that i would just use the GlobalConfiguration package: https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Flutter-Global-Config

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Rodrigo. I don't need to rebuild widgets, I just need professional way of storing and retrieving value. As I think ```static``` would be too junior way of handling things.